# BPDU Guard With RSTP Devices

Tags: spanning-tree, ieee-802.1w

I am attempting to secure our switches with BPDU Guard. I have it enabled and I have a pieces of equipment with 2 NIC ports on them of which they can be daisy chained together for data collection. When I plug in one of these devices, the port it is plugged into it throws a BPDU alert and sets the port to `err-disable`. As far as I know this will continue to happen if I used these devices. Does this mean I can't employ BPDU Guard or is there something we can do to keep the BPDU Guard on and plug in these devices?

Comment: Sounds like this "equipment" is sending BPDUs.  But you've provided so little detail, it's really impossible to tell for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*bpdu-guard* disables a port when it receives (unwanted) BPDUs. That is its design. You cannot use *bpdu-guard* with devices that you expect to emit BPDUs in general. The only way to keep *bpdu-guard* enabled productively is to make those device stop sending BPDUs.

If you want to ignore BPDUs from a port you should instead use *bpdu-filter* (ignoring BPDUs generally, effectively disabling STP for that port) and/or *tcn-guard* (just ignoring topology change notifications), in combination with *root-guard* (preventing a port to become root port).

If you must filter BPDUs but still need to have loop detection, some devices feature a *loop guard* that disables a port when it detects a loop (usually by sending out and potentially receiving signed probing frames). Other damage control measures for loops include limiting broadcast rates.

Comment: So leaving BPDU guard on I can still have "guard root" on as well as a number of other STP methods correct?

Comment: Yes - generally, you can use a couple of other features to secure STP, as alternatives to (the rather blunt) bpdu-guard. I'd recommend using root-guard and tcn-guard an edge ports (and even on most intermediate ports) in any case.